# Emptydatatext is not working in gridview from code behind and front end as well

Tags: c#, asp.net

My grid is opening on a button click on a web page.
I tried to put empty grid meesage from code behind like below

```
grdHistoricalData.EmptyDataText = "No Data Found!";
```

And from the front end as well by below gridview property  :

```
EmptyDataText="No Records Found !"
```

But its still not showing `"No Data Found message"`

```
if (ListOfData.Any()) 
{ 
    grdHistoricalData.DataSource = ListOfData;
    grdHistoricalData.DataBind(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    grdHistoricalData.EmptyDataText = "No Data Found!"; 
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you bind anything in the gridview ? If not it won't come out.. You must bind in empty datatable

Comment: @nicholas put the condition like this

Comment: if (ListOfData.Any())
                {
                    

                    grdHistoricalData.DataSource = ListOfData;
                    grdHistoricalData.DataBind();

                }
                else
                {
                    grdHistoricalData.EmptyDataText = "No Data Found!";
                   
          
                }

Comment: It will not work like this... You try to bind new DataTable() to the gridview.... It should fix your problem put your EmptyDataText in code in front will do. The code you are doing is just setting the text not binding data to gridview

Comment: @Nicholas you were correct I changed the condition and its working .now I am binding the grid in else condition as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to following.. Should be working fine

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdHistoricalData" runat="server" 
EmptyDataText="No Data Found!"></asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
if (ListOfData.Any()) 
{ 
    grdHistoricalData.DataSource = ListOfData;
    grdHistoricalData.DataBind(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    // grdHistoricalData.EmptyDataText = "No Data Found!"; 
    grdHistoricalData.DataSource = new DataTable();
    grdHistoricalData.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why new DataTable();   ?   Removing the if (ListOfData.Any())  condition won/t do it  ?

Comment: @pravprab Just in case he want to do the condition... Remove it will work but still need to make sure it's not null.. Null won't bind...The Empty message won't come out